# Create a file in a different directory with SSH cat

Tags: php, ssh, cat

I am trying to create a file automatically through PHP, but with the unix cat commands through SSH. I can create a file in the directory I am in, but I want to create a file in a different directory. This is the code that creates the file in the directory I am in:

```
$sPath = "/minecraft/servers/";
$sSavingCode = "server.properties";      
echo $ssh->exec("cat >".$sSavingCode." <<".$sPath."
    test");
```

This code gives this error, but it creates the file in the directory I am in:

> bash: line 1: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `/minecraft/servers/')

I just need a way to create the file in a different directory. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the path (`$sSavingCode`) as the delimiter for the heredoc statement. You should try the following statement. It uses the literal `EOF` as the delimiter for the heredoc section:

```
echo $ssh->exec("cat > $sPath/$sSavingCode <<EOF
    test
EOF
");
```

Comment: That gives the error _bash: /minecraft/servers/server.properties: No such file or directory_

Comment: If it is a Linux server I would expect that this is a relative path to your home directory. Remove the leading `/` before minecraft

Comment: You are welcome! I have a question. You do you login? Using keys? Or does the library also support passwords? (and key with password?)

Comment: `<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('$IP');
if (!$ssh->login('$user', '$password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$sPath = "minecraft/servers/";
$sSavingCode = "server.properties";

echo $ssh->exec("cat > $sPath$sSavingCode <<EOF
test
EOF
");
`
That is my code that I am using. (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Understood. Will have a look at this library. Thanks!